# A question about using CNN network, changing data as 4-dim

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, predict

I tried to import pictures from the camera and I could get 3-dim data from the image.

```
    img = WebcamModule.getImg(True, size=[240,120])

    img = image.img_to_array(img)
```

[image]

then, from the code below I tried to expand one more dimention which is batch size. But it doesn't work.
How do I import batch size into the data.
There is a picture of the result below.

```
    img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
```

Finally, the code below for predicting doesn't work.

```
    val = float(model.predict(img))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
input = input_raw[np.newaxis, ...]
prediction = model.predict(input)
pred = np.squeeze(prediction)
draw(pred)
```

Check the shape of the image and the image the network wants, check if the model is channel first or channel last, but this always worked for me.